# Blender-GIS Get SRTM wont work

Tags: add-on, height-map

Hey I'm running Blender 3.0 and every time I try to get the elevation Data from the Website it shows me this Error: "Cannot reach OpenTopography Webservice, check logs for more Infos".
So if i look into the logs it only says multiple times: "2022-02-20 22:21:36,228 - BlenderGIS-master.core.basemaps.mapservice - ERROR - Can't download tile x136283 y87646. Error <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>" and then "2022-02-20 22:26:25,578 - BlenderGIS-master.operators.io_get_dem - ERROR - Http request fails url:https://portal.opentopography.org/API/globaldem?demtype=SRTMGL1&west=7.144606444922421&east=7.167832519360552&south=51.089448021248955&north=51.100347790999045&outputFormat=GTiff, code:401, error:401". Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? In another post someone said that i need an API Key. Can someone tell me how to add this key into the addon?

Comment: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/issues/305

Comment: its not a network issue

Comment: I'm getting the same error you are. When I went to the web address in the error, it shows me the following message:
"<error>Error: This dataset requires an API Key for access.</error>" Looks like it needs a key that isn't being provided, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get an API Key by creating an account with opentopography.org
2. In Blender on the GIS tab click "Preferences" then "Add-ons"
3. Find the "Elevation server:" Use drop-down menu and select "OpenTopography SRTM 30m" Click "Edit."
4. In the "url template" add "&API_Key=[your key number]" at the end of the existing url.
5. Click Ok

You can do this for both the OpenTopography SRTM 30m & SRTM 90m

Answer (score 1):

BINGO - Error FIXED on SRTM!!!! .... I did a new install, loaded the GIS addon and same constant error on new and old versions.  Read all the threads and finally figured it out myself. When I copied and pasted the API code, I didn't notice there was a single empty space in the beginning of the code, far left.  Once I deleted the space you could hardly even see, it worked like a charm as it should. Here is the fix: https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/pull/840

Many people say it's the new version but my fix worked on all old and new versions mac and PC